# Stretching columns on TableLayout has no effect

Tags: android

I am working on an android project and I am making use of the table layout but I am experiencing an issue.

As mentioned in the title, I am using a TableLayout and trying to stretch all of the columns to fit the screen but for some reason it has no affect, and all the columns are squished over to the left.

Below is the XML layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal">
        <HorizontalScrollView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TableLayout android:id="@+id/resultTable"
                android:stretchColumns="*"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TableLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is how I am populating the TableLayout

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try
                    {
                        Log.d("Returned in Result", String.valueOf(result.length()));
                        resultTable.removeAllViews();
                        resultTable.setStretchAllColumns(true);
                        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++)
                        {
                            TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
                            JSONArray array = result.getJSONArray(i);
                            Log.d("Returned in Result", "Loaded Columns: " + String.valueOf(array.length()));
                            for (int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++)
                            {
                                //LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                                //LayoutParams parms = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                //linearLayout.setLayoutParams(parms);

                                TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
                                textView.setText(array.getString(j));
                                textView.setSingleLine();
                                //linearLayout.addView(textView);
                                tr.addView(textView);
                            }
                            resultTable.addView(tr);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log.e("Load Result", ex.toString());
                        CrashReporter.ReportCrash(ex, Severity.Critical);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

**UPDATE**

I've found it the `HorizontalScrollView` that is causing the columns to not stretch. If I remeove the horizontal scroll view it works fine but with the horizontal scroll view the columns don't stretch. How can I get this working as I need to have the horizontal scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I had something similar , I didn't had any table layout but I wanted to have a scroll view inside a relative layout so I had to do something like ,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/theme"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This mighy not be of any use but this is what made my "columns are squished over to the left." problem solved. 
**EDIT:** Try having your Linear Layout inside Scroll view.